# I can't install environement XTBApi

Tags: python, api

I am a trader, I want to use the XTB API to access the account,T try to learn Python I found XTBApi I install it Windows (python3 -m venv env)
but when I enter the command (. \ venv \ Scripts \ activate) it doesn't work: The specified path could not be found.
What do I have to do?
Thanks

How can i convert linux script to windows script :

git clone git@github.com:federico123579/XTBApi.git
cd XTBApi/
python3 -m venv env
. env/bin/activate
pip install .

Answer (score 0):

From what I know of venv, activate is found in bin, try

```
venv/bin/activate
```

Comment: `activate` is a file, not a folder (trailing slash).

Comment: thanks updated typo

Comment: XTBApi\env\Scripts\activate on widows but i can't execute it, activate.bat also in the same path

Comment: can you provide what error you are getting

Comment: git clone git@github.com:federico123579/XTBApi.git
cd XTBApi/
python3 -m venv env
. env/bin/activate (Error here : "." is not a command )

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70453702/i-cant-install-environement-xtbapi/70454195#comment124541708_70453778) `XTBApi\env\Scripts\activate.bat` being present.

Execute **that** file because that's written in Windows' scripting language (Batch) instead of Linux/UNIX's scripting language (Bash). Those aren't compatible, nor have the same syntax.

- `XTBApi\env\Scripts\activate` -> Bash (for [msys2](https://www.msys2.org) or similar things that have Bash interpreter)
- `XTBApi\env\Scripts\activate.bat` -> Batch (for `cmd.exe`)

There should also be a `.ps1` file for Powershell, if you are using it.